# C: Unable to receive input using scanf()

Tags: c, scanf

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{

    float p, r, t;
    char ch = 'y';

    do
    {
        printf("Enter principal: ");
        scanf("%f", &p);

        printf("Enter rate: ");
        scanf("%f", &r);

        printf("Enter t: ");
        scanf("%f", &t);

        printf("SI = %f", (p *r * t)/100 );

        printf("\nCalculate SI one more time ? ('Y' for Yes, 'n' for no ) : ");
        ch = getchar();


    }while(ch == 'y'); 

    return 0;

}
```

Output:

```
Enter principal: 1334
Enter rate: 4
Enter t: 2
SI = 106.720000
Calculate SI one more time ? ('Y' for Yes, 'n' for no ) :
Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 5.359 s
Press any key to continue.
```

As you can see i am unable to calculate SI second time ?? What is the problem ?

I even tried replacing getchar() by scanf() but it is still not working

Comment: `ch = getchar();` there is a `newline` still in the input buffer, left by the previous `scanf`.

Comment: @WeatherVane will you pls explain what's going on ?

Comment: `scanf` with most formats (but not `%c`) eats up *leading* whitespace but leaves anything subsequent, in the input buffer. The character based input functions, take exactly whatever is there.

Comment: @WeatherVane what's the solution

Comment: `scanf(" %c", &ch);` note the space before `%c` which will eat leading whitespace like the other format specifiers do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`scanf` stops reading when the number is complete (at the first char that cannot be a part of it).

So the last of your `scanf` (for t) *stops* reading just before the <kbd>RET</kbd> you pressed after typing t's value. The `getchar()` then reads the next char, which is a `'\n'` (the <kbd>RET</kbd>), and that is not equals to 'y', so it ends.

You should not mix multiple input methods; if you use `scanf`, stay with `scanf`, and have it read one char (`scanf(" %c",&ch);`) or some other solution; or read the `'\n'` with an extra `getchar()` after the `scanf` and ignore it.